# loading html the right way to get stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString working

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview, uiwebview

I'm trying to get stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to work.
I'm sure i load the html file wrong I just dont see what i do wrong.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{   
// Load the index.html file as a string from the file system
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
  NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Load/pass it in to webView
  [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I pass/send the javascript event to index.html:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"displayName('name');"];
}
```

What do i do wrong?

Comment: I found the reason why it didn't work... "displayName('name');" was sent to early. While webView was finished loading. The content (index.html) wasn't finished loading and therefor got the event to early.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for this function.

```
NSString *fullURL = @"url";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

FinishLoad

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViews {
NSString *testString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"[ID]\").innerHTML;"];
    [webView loadHTMLString:testString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: To comment on your code. Where do you declare testString? and the file is in the resources bundle in the app and not online.

Comment: I edited my code, I didn't yet try this code for offline use.